# Как сверстать двухстрочное меню?

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

[image: Нужно сверстать такое двухстрочное меню.]

```css
/* BASE SETTINGS */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.inner-html {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* HEADER */

.header {
  padding-top: 43px;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Pacifico", "Roboto";
  font-size: 41px;
  display: inline;
  width: 7%;
  float: left;
}


/* NAV MENU */

.nav {
  padding-left: 15vw;
  width: 620px;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.navigation li ul {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.navigation li ul li:nth-child(1) a {
  color: #a5a5a5;
}

.navigation li ul li:nth-child(2) a {
  color: #474747;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="inner-html">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="logo">Blitz</div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/about">Who  are  we?</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/projects">MY  Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="/projects">PROJECTS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/news">Latest  News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/news">BLOG</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/contact">Get  in  touch</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

1. Оно не адапативное. Как его сделать адаптивным ?
2. Костыль для `.nav` в виде  `width:620px;`. Как исправить?

Comment: Вы, батенька, что именно имеете ввиду под словом адаптивный?

Comment: @Air на всех разрешениях дисплея было приятно смотреть на мой сайт

Comment: Очень общий вопрос...

Answer (score 2):

Для тренировки .. смотрите и учитесь

Для проверки адаптивности : [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/lenskyuser/hrpr6bx6/1/)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

span.trigger {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

li {
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

li:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

li p {
  color: #ccc;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

li:hover p {
  color: red;
  opacity: .5;
}

li span {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}

.brand {
  font-family: "Pacifico";
  font-size: 2.4em;
  font-weight: 900;
}

@media (max-width:640px) {
  li p {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  section {
    position: relative;
  }
  span.trigger {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  span.trigger i {
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #222;
    margin: 4px auto;
  }
  ul li {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <span class="trigger">
 <i></i>
 <i></i>
 <i></i>
</span>
  <span class="brand">
 blitz
</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <p>Homepage</p>
        <span>home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <p>wo are wy</p>
        <span>about</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <p>my portfolio</p>
        <span>projects</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <p>latest news</p>
        <span>blog</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <p>get in touch</p>
        <span>contacts</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: проверил для мобильников... меню-гамбургер не работает( Или это толко у меня?

Comment: я не писал js - видно же что js нету

Comment: Я подумал, что ты в CSS реализовал код...

Comment: @Antonio112009 я и так в css его сделал

Comment: Я к тому, что мену не "расскривается" при наведении на нее

Comment: @Antonio112009   а я и ни делал что бы оно раскрывалось - в вопросе не было такого , было сказано "адаптировать"   если автор не умеет то пускай попросит

Comment: kk.............

Comment: @Antonio112009  так это тебе надо что ли ?

Comment: Mne - net.prosto iz interesa sprosil